# Why did the internet price rise in the last 5 years in Germany?

Tags: price, germany

5 years ago a casual internet connection with 10 Mbit and telephone connection cost about 20 € per month in Germany.

Today, the chepest contract that I could find in Germany is an internet connections with 16 Mbit and telephone flat for landline, which costs monthly 30 €.

Why did the price rise about 50%? The infrastructure has already been build and the difference between 16 Mbit and 10 Mbit isn't that big.

Comment: Price per Mbit is close to the same though. 20€ / 10 Mbit = 2 € / Mbit * 16 = 32 € > 30€. By that logic prices have actually dropped a bit.